# DatagramSocket socket stop receiving packet

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I wrote a test program with a DatagramSocket to Receive data. but after receive 5 or 6 packet, this isn't receive more packet!

Does anybody have a solution for this?

My test Code is:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Listen();
        }
private async void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket();

            socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;

            //You can use any port that is not currently in use already on the machine.
            string serverPort = "1337";

            //Bind the socket to the serverPort so that we can start listening for UDP messages from the UDP echo client.
            await socket.BindServiceNameAsync(serverPort);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle exception.
        }
    }

    public async void Socket_MessageReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Read the message that was received from the UDP echo client.
        Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);

        string message = await reader.ReadLineAsync();


        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                Alpha.Text = message;


            }
            );
        }
```

I have traced with wireshark to check that I am receiving data, it gets that but in my visual studio solutions it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked, whether the target solution has it's [network capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enable-device-capabilities) enabled?

Comment: yes it's enable

Comment: been working on this too.. never got it working in UWP for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it happens to be you open another instance of your UDP Listener, or you Initialize in wrong Place!

Answer (score 2):

I used Control.InboundBufferSizeInBytes then it works correctly!

```
        listener = new DatagramSocket();
        listener.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
        listener.Control.InboundBufferSizeInBytes = 1;

        await listener.BindServiceNameAsync("1337");
```